# Android Google maps Load in background

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to load Google Maps on the background? And while it is loading show it in the actionbar with a progressbar?

Now I have a MapActivity, and when I start it it takes some time. But I only see a black screen after a few seconds it goes on... (This does not happen on my Galaxy Nexus, so I guess it has to do with the speed of the device..)

Answer (score -3):

you can use

```
 AsyncTask<Uri, Void, ContactInfo> task = new AsyncTask<Uri, Void, ContactInfo>() {

            @Override
            protected ContactInfo doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

                         // here your code for loading maps
                return ;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ContactInfo result) {


            }
        };

        task.execute();
```

Comment: That's what I don't understand. You only have to place an Mapview in the xml. There is no code to load.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

check this link